# Using custom classes in FXML without packages

Tags: javafx, fxml

There are several other question regarding this topic, but they all use files placed in packages unlike mine. I have three simple files:

1. FXMLtest.java - The main class extending `Application`
2. Bean.java - extends `Circle`. Has an extra property which follows java bean conventions
3. view2.fxml

(all files are in the same folder)
I infer (from the stackrace) that the error arises since `FXMLLoader` is unable to locate `Bean`, which is on the scene graph in `view2.fxml`. Perhaps it has something to do with not using a package. If so, I would just like to know why packages are necessary. Given below are the three files and the stack trace.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
public class FXMLtest extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view2.fxml")), 300,100);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
public class Bean extends Button{
    private SimpleDoubleProperty foo;
    Bean(){
        super();
    }
    void setFoo(double x){
        foo.set(x);
    }
    double getFoo(){
        return foo.get();
    }
    SimpleDoubleProperty fooProperty(){
        return foo;
    }
}
```

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import Bean?>
<Pane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
   <children>
      <Button text="testButton" />
      <Bean foo="4.4" text="button2" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "JavaFX BlueJ Helper" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/java/view2.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at FXMLtest.start(FXMLtest.java:10)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2899)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Use of the default package is discouraged in general in Java. Why not just put the classes in packages as usual?

Comment: I use blueJ. I am not sure what package structure to use, and there are only 3 files. I did try putting the classes in a package but there were still errors.

Comment: Just put all three in a named package. Follow the [naming conventions for Java packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)